# angular.js/backbone.js without changing the address bar

Tags: node.js, angularjs, backbone.js, socket.io, pug

It seems that angular.js and backbone.js both prefer the user to change the browser state (via the address bar) and then they will re-act regarding the defined `routes`. That is still a single-page web application, but in my case, I really don't need to change the address bar when user is interacting with the application and I prefer to avoid it as much as possible also.

As a newbie in both angular.js and backbone.js, I'm facing difficulty on how to structure my single-page web application while using either angular.js or backbone.js, but without touching the address bar.

I have a node.js, jade and socket.io setup (without express.js), and the socket.io is the main way of communication between client and server.

To be more specific, imagine that I'm loading the dashbaord.jade, now how can I inject some partials into the main markup when socket.io detects an event? Can I replace the entire dashbaord.jade also - the already rendered markup?

Comment: So what's the problem? Don't change the url! don't use router and make your app just interact with user by mouse (or keyboard) events or just update model or views every single time socket send event!!

Comment: @KiTO hey! Any reference, tutorial, similar SO question? I'm stuck there man ... what you said is exactly what I'm asking here!

Comment: Ok, great problems there. The Backbone way (I'm not familiar with angular,jade and node!) : don't create any router. that's simple enough! Impelement a new model to use socket and by any event of socket do appropriate action. In that model when socket sends event (`IO.on('event')`) load the template (how! donno jade way!) load models (could be data from of socket event) and render views. I haven't seen any tutorial for this specific problem.

Comment: @KiTO thank you! I will give it a try ... if you post it as an answer I'd upvote also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's the problem? Don't change the url! don't use router and make your app just interact with user by mouse (or keyboard) events or just update model or views every single time socket send event!!

My solution : don't create any `router`, implement new class to use socket and by any event of socket do appropriate action. In that class define a method for each socket event, that loads template and model (maybe return data from socketIO event) and render view by those data.